# Are there any legal issues with designing a font that looks too close to a custom design?

Tags: fonts, legal

There are the so-called "custom fonts/typefaces" that are custom designs of fonts that are not available on the market. These are usually comissioned by companies (specially large ones).

What are the risks (if any) of designing a font that is close (or even too close) to a custom font design?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a legal question, not a design question.

Comment: Legal questions are off-topic here. Ask your lawyer/a legal expert.

Comment: Most of the work in making a font is in the kerning table. Hopefully you are not in Germany or Austria as they have pretty restrictive rules for fonts. Anyway the sooner you stop using other peoples IP for your stuff the sooner you will start making money of of things you make.

Comment: If you just tell us what font you have in mind, there's a pretty good chance we can recommend something like it or even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to open up a new thread showing the font you mean and asking if anyone can recommend something like it. Very few fonts are totally original. I think it's much more likely someone here can recommend a font that's similar to the one you like than you have to draw your own. Or should, ethically, for that matter. We had a discussion recently about an Apple Watch face font Apple said was custom, there are plenty of fonts fairly similar.

On your question: IANAL. In many countries, fonts cannot be copyrighted, only the digital data can. So the second you open up their digital font file and change a few curve points you're <s>going to jail</s> in trouble. It's easy to hide things in font data to make it obvious you've copied. And even if you're clever, [normally the original creator can spot what you've done](https://twitter.com/paulg/status/1195709791991222273). Making a font involves lots of tiny decisions, and if you seem to always make the same ones as the original creator it's not hard to spot, like a plagiarized answer that copies out the textbook, all the points in the same structure.

Drawing your own font is likely safer. Many fonts out there are what you might call "similar" to others. My general thought is that the more a font feels like a picture than a letterform, the more trouble you're in. Imagine say a [font made up of flowers](https://www.etsy.com/listing/189895753/digital-font-flower-garden-font-digital), that would probably be the most risky to copy because it's more like art that happens to be in the shape of letters.

MyFonts contains some pretty sketchy fonts which seem to suggest you can get away with a lot, including [this](https://www.fonts.com/font/untype/tectonica) which is a pretty obvious rip-off of [this](https://slate.com/human-interest/2015/02/obsidian-by-jonathan-hoefler-and-andy-clymer-of-hoefler-co-is-a-contemporary-font-with-roots-in-the-industrial-revolution.html) (which MyFonts' parent company [now own the rights to](https://www.monotype.com/company/news/monotype-announces-acquisition-iconic-type-foundry-hoeflerco), funnily enough).